# Change a particular class background color on another div click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background color of a div on `click` of another div.
I tried this

HTML

```
<div class="post-main-content">
    <br /><hr />
    <p>
    <br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, 
    iusto quasi eum, delectus, soluta aliquam modi suscipit non fuga fugiat 
    nemo ullam eos? Eaque soluta esse, dolore voluptates vitae sunt 
    recusandae libero provident accusantium ex nemo quaerat quidem cumque 
    corrupti voluptatibus cum debitis assumenda sequi veniam corporis quam 
    <p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
const backChange = document.querySelector('post-main-content').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.backChange.style.background = "black"
})
```

Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

add a dot in `querySelector`

```
const backChange = document.querySelector('.post-main-content');
backChange.addEventListener("click", function(){
    backChange.style.background = "black";
});
```